# Switch between groups

Tags: organic-groups

Is there any easy way to switch between groups? Let's say if a user is a member of two groups, I would like a widget with a dropdown (or alike) for the user to select current group.

Comment: Have you tried [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) yet? You can easily create a block containing all the groups the current user is a member of.

Comment: @Turion Of course! Just created a block view now, and it seems to work good. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with drop down (Jump menu) though, as it seems to be linked to the path `/[title of the node]`, while ie. the table format is linked to `/node/[# of the node]`.

Comment: I don't understand. What does the drop down menu have to do with path aliasing? Are you already using a particular module for the drop down menu?